# Daily Marvel indices - is it safe to remove?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

I have indices like this:

```
health status index              pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   .marvel-2015.08.15   1   1      11091            0     11.6mb         17.6mb 
yellow open   myindex              5   1     104321        14891     22.5mb         32.7mb 
yellow open   .marvel-2015.08.17   1   1      62214            0     70.2mb         90.9mb
```

The index that starts with ".marvel" gets created on the daily basis. What are these? Is it safe to remove them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.marvel` indices come from Marvel, a plugin developed by Elastic to help monitoring a cluster.

At regular intervals, statistical data is being indexed into today's `.marvel` index by a Marvel agent. With data from those indices, one can look at various graphs (heap usage, load, indexing rate, search rate, free disk space etc. etc.) over time: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/dashboards.html

Is it safe to delete the `.marvel` indices as long as you don't want to keep monitoring data over time. In case you use the dashboards from the link above, these will not contain any historical data about the cluster. But, deleting those indices will not make your cluster go red or something similar.